# How do you create a module specific router in the Zend Frameowrk?

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration

I have the following router in my Zend Framework application.ini:

```
resources.router.routes.route_id.route = "/artists/:uid"
resources.router.routes.route_id.defaults.module = "admin"
resources.router.routes.route_id.defaults.controller = "showrooms"
resources.router.routes.route_id.defaults.action = "edit"
```

It works and routes "/artists/:uid" to the correct location.

This application is modular and the above routing applies to every module.

**How do you make the routing apply to only one module?**

I have the following modules:

Admin:
admin.site.com

Corp:
corp.site.com

Other:
other.site.com

I only want the above routing to apply if the user hits the **Corp** module.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Routing is what determines the module, so what do you mean by "the above routing applies to every module"? Your route will match any requests to `/artists/something` - in what situation should it not match?

Comment: I have edited the question as it's not clear in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to route the subdomain to the corp module

to do that you must tell zend route to use hostname routing

```ini
routes.corp.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
routes.corp.route = "corp.:domain.:tld"
```

this way the subdoamin corp on all domains on all topleveldomains will be routed. If you want it only for site.com make it

```ini
routes.corp.route = "corp.site.com"
```

Now that you routed the subdomain you can set it up for sending it to a module by adding it to the defaults

```ini
routes.corp.defaults.module = "corp"
```

to let it route as "normal" connect it to the default route by doing

```ini
routes.corp.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.corp.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
routes.corp.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.corp.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

so that corp.site.com/news/view/id/1 will go to the newsController in the corp module